# Write multiple files with same string without hanging the UI

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android App that changes the CPU Frequency when a foreground app changes. The frequencies for the foreground app is defined in my application itself. But while changing the frequencies my app has to open multiple system files and replace the frequency with my text. This makes my UI slow and when I change apps continuously, it makes the systemUI crash. What can I do to write these multiple files all together at the same time?

I have tried using ASynctaskLoader but that too crashes the SystemUI later.

```
public static boolean setFreq(String max_freq, String min_freq) {
       ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(max_freq.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
       ByteArrayInputStream inputStream1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(min_freq.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

       SuFileOutputStream outputStream;
        SuFileOutputStream outputStream1;
        try {
            if (max_freq != null) {
                int cpus = 0;
                while (true) {
                    SuFile f = new SuFile(CPUActivity.MAX_FREQ_PATH.replace("cpu0", "cpu" + cpus));
                    SuFile f1 = new SuFile(CPUActivity.MIN_FREQ_PATH.replace("cpu0", "cpu" + cpus));

                    outputStream = new SuFileOutputStream(f);
                    outputStream1 = new SuFileOutputStream(f1);

                    ShellUtils.pump(inputStream, outputStream);
                    ShellUtils.pump(inputStream1, outputStream1);

                    if (!f.exists()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    cpus++;
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `SuFile` and `SuFileOutputStream` are your custom implementations extending Java `File` and `FileOutputStream` classes.

Couple of points need to be fixed first.

1. `f.exists()` check should be before initializing `OutputStream`, otherwise it will create the file before checking exists or not. This makes your while loop to become an infinite loop.
2. as @Daryll suggested, use the number of CPUs with while/for loop. I suggest using for loop.
3. close your streams after `pump(..)` method call.
4. If you want to keep the main thread free, then you can do something like this,

see this code segment:

```
public static void setFreq(final String max_freq, final String min_freq) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        //Put all the stuff here
    }).start();
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried it and this works fine. So if u have seen my that part of code you can see that it edits many files all together. is there any other way to change cpu frequencies by just editing one file?

Answer (score 0):

Determine the number of CPUs before hand and use that number in your loop rather than using a while (true) having to do SuFile.exists() every cycle.

I don't know what SuFileOutputStream is but you may need to close those file output streams or find a faster way to write the file if that implementation is too slow.

Comment: The number of CPUs are determined before hand itself. SuFileOutputStream is the same as FileOutputStream but that is used for dealing with root file that require su permissions. Thats just a modification of FileOutputStream. So you mean that after i pump those files, i should close each file first and then move to second file?